# How To Make ScrollView Scroll in both x and y Direction At Same Time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, scrollview

I will need to make a table which will be long and overflow off screen.

I know scrollview can be use do something like this, but it is limited to scrolling in either vertical or horizontal direction.

How can I make it scroll in both direction at same time.

Or if there is any other way to do, kindy share with me.

Thanks.

I haven't really tried any option as I could think of known presently

```
<ScrollView
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{
            paddingBottom: Padding.lg,
            marginBottom: 100
        }}
        >
          {inventories.map((item, index) => {
            return <InventoryResult item={item} key={index} />;
          })}
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nest one `ScrollView` inside the other. Set the inner one to be horizontal.

```
<ScrollView>
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
  //content
</ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Otherwise, I found this [package.](https://github.com/cesardeazevedo/react-native-nested-scroll-view) Maybe give it a try.

Comment: Great idea, never thought of that.

Comment: Let me know whether this works for you. Happy to help further. [ would also appreciate an  upvote if you like the answer ;) ]

Comment: @IbrahimEemaan Did this solve your problem? Would love to hear back :)

Comment: Sorry @austin-poulson , I had no chance to test it since I was not given the task anymore. But I hope someone else would find it useful. Thanks for your input.